# Calling Json Object inside a Json Array but not getting output

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, object

I m calling an API using volley which is in the form of JSON. That JSON has JSON objects inside a JSON array. I have written a code calling JSONArrayRequest first then I run a loop to find all the objects inside that array after that I get state name through getString and matches it the state name which is pressed if it same then next loop runs to find all the "district" name and "active" from the districtData. I am not able to get output but in ErrorResponse toast, I get the full array with all its data of API.

if I am changing **"JSONObject array = object1.getJSONObject("districtData");"**
to **"JSONArray array = object1.getJSONArray("districtData");** " I am getting error screenshot attached bellow...

if not changing this **"JSONObject array = object1.getJSONObject("districtData");"**
then I don't know what to write here **"JSONObject object2 = array.getJSONObject(/*What To do after that, what to enter here pls tell me... I m new to this*/);"** because whatever I m writing there toast's me that not getting the value of what I m entring.

**Some part of JSON**

[ {
    "state": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
    "statecode": "AN",
    "districtData": [
      {
        "district": "North and Middle Andaman",
        "notes": "",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "district": "South Andaman",
        "notes": "",
        "active": 10,
        "confirmed": 20,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 10,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 4,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "district": "Unknown",
        "notes": "",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

```
private void getData2(){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    final String clickedState = getIntent().getStringExtra("stateName");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    String url = "https://api.covid19india.org/v2/state_district_wise.json";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        assert clickedState != null;
                        JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject(clickedState);
                        JSONObject array = object1.getJSONObject("districtData");
                        for (int i = 0; i<array.length();i++){
                            JSONObject object2 = array.getJSONObject(/*What To do after that, what to enter here pls tel me... I m new to this*/);
                            String s1 = object2.getString("district");
                            String s2 = object2.getString("active");
                            StateList item = new StateList(s1,s2);
                            mData2.add(item);
                            initRecyclerView();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
private void initRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: initRecyclerView");
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.districtsDetailedRecycler);
    StateDistrictsAdapter adapter2 = new StateDistrictsAdapter(mData2,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

}

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xESQd.jpg)

Comment: paste the json in your qesution not in link.

Comment: Ok, but JSON has a very long data.

Comment: just include a portion of it, not all of it.

Comment: I got new thing that after doing JsonArrayRequest compiler directly jumps to new Response.ErrorListener without going to new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()

Comment: Please Help me...

Comment: The json from the link is not a JSON array, its a JSONObejct with named objects

Comment: ```JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("districtData");``` cant work as well, since districtData is aobejct ```{ ... } ``` and not a array ```[ ... ]````

Comment: I changed my code but still not getting. @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: none of the objects are array, nor you can access with an index, you have to or map every name of the attributes names. Plus the json you posted is different from the one from the URL, the one you mentioned is a valid JSON array

Comment: sry, URL mentioned in the code is wrong I Changed it now... **"https://api.covid19india.org/v2/state_district_wise.json"**

Comment: Thank u so much @MarcosVasconcelos that was a silly mistake by me...I m very very sry. I get My result

Comment: Mr. @MarcosVasconcelos, Can u pls help me in this Stack Overflow Question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351287/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-time-in-android-while-fetchin