# 'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, searchview

My SearchView not works... I m trying to search in RecyclerView but it through an error Of JavaExeption...I have done everyThing that I can do, but the problem is still there where it was. Pls guide me I am a student.
'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference

**SupportAdapter code**

```
public class SupportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SupportAdapter.viewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private static final  String TAG = "SupportAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private List<SupportList> mData;
    private List<SupportList> mDataFull;

public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView Category;
    private TextView City;
    private TextView Contact;
    private TextView Description;
    private TextView Organisation;
    private TextView Phone;
    private TextView State;
    private LinearLayout container;

    private viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

       container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.supportContainer);
        Category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        City = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        Contact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
        Description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        Organisation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_of_org);
        Phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        State = itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);

    }
}

public SupportAdapter(Context mContext, List<SupportList> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    mDataFull = new ArrayList<>(mData);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.search_item_list,parent,false);

    return new viewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SupportAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_scale_animation));
    holder.Category.setText(mData.get(position).getCategory());
    holder.City.setText(mData.get(position).getCity());
    holder.Contact.setText(mData.get(position).getContact());
    holder.Description.setText(mData.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.Organisation.setText(mData.get(position).getOrganisation());
    holder.Phone.setText(mData.get(position).getPhone());
    holder.State.setText(mData.get(position).getState());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return mDataFullFilter;
}

private Filter mDataFullFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<SupportList> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(mDataFull);
        }else {
            String filterPattern =constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(SupportList item : mDataFull){
                if(item.getCity().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
                else if (item.getCity().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        mData.clear();
        mData.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

**SearchFragment**

```
private RecyclerView NewRecyclerView;
private SupportAdapter supportAdapter;
private List<SupportList> mData;
private SearchView searchItem;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    searchItem = root.findViewById(R.id.searchItem);
    NewRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.searchList);
    supportAdapter = new SupportAdapter (getContext(),mData);
    NewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    NewRecyclerView.setAdapter(supportAdapter);


    return root;
}




@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    getSupport();

    searchItem.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            supportAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            supportAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

**Logcat**

```
2020-04-28 00:58:02.828 12382-12382/com.praso.indiacovid_19 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.praso.indiacovid_19, PID: 12382
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.praso.indiacovid_19.ui.search.SearchFragment.onCreate(SearchFragment.java:64)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

Comment: It looks like you meant to override `onViewCreated()`, instead of `onCreate()`.

Comment: It is a fragment that's why... @MikeM.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's still what I mean, though. A `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` runs before its `onCreateView()` method, which is why you're getting that `NullPointerException`. If you move that code to `onViewCreated()`, it'll work, because that method runs after `onCreateView()`. At least, you shouldn't get that particular NPE anymore.

Comment: ok, I m going trying It. Mr. @MikeM.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @MikeM I get the Result. Can u ls help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351287/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-time-in-android-while-fetchin

Answer (score 2):

res/menu/menu_main.xml

```
      <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />
```

Just make sure to put this line in your code inside the manu

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```